# Task post-processing to start soon after 2 tasks are done

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I have a core task retreiving me some core data and multiple other sub-tasks fetching extra data. Would like to run some enricher process to the core data as soon as the core task and any of the sub-task is ready. Would you know how to do so?

Thought about something like this but not sure it's the doing what I want:

```
// Starting the tasks
var coreDataTask = new Task(...);
var extraDataTask1 = new Task(...);
var extraDataTask2 = new Task(...);

coreDataTask.Start();
extraDataTask1.Start();
extraDataTask2.Start();

// Enriching the results
Task.WaitAll(coreDataTask, extraDataTask1);
EnrichCore(coreDataTask.Results, extraDataTask1.Results);

Task.WaitAll(coreDataTask, extraDataTask2);
EnrichCore(coreDataTask.Results, extraDataTask2.Results);
```

Also given the enrichement is on the same core object, guess I would need to lock it somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how is coreDataTask started twice? and you just want to add the data from ext1 & ext2 to the coreData to store or to actually do something with it?

Comment: I don't want to start it twice, maybe my code is wrong. I just want to get my core data once, then enrich it with ext1 & ext2 data as soon as they are ready

Comment: Ah okay, so i'd use a concurrentStack which is threadsafe and an event to signal incoming data, so the coreDataTask can reorganize the data in the stack maybe to another list or something

Comment: and i wouldnt wait on a task if its not really needed. You want to process every extTask parrallel so dont wait for any of them

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Maybe I miss your point but not sure how the concurrentStack can help. The data is fairly complex, so what I need is that once ready I want to start some enrichers: Enrich(core,ext1) and Enrich(core,ext2)... not really about stacking the data somewhere.

Comment: okay i'll try to be more detailed ^^ and maybe didnt get your intention right. So you have 'n' extTasks, which return data at a unknown time. And you want to handle this data as soon as a result is available? But you have only one coreDataTask. The solution i thought about was, as soon as a result is there a event gets fired and the data is temporarily stored in the stack (or queue), so the single coreTask can be enriched with all the data (enrich core with extN), but its only one thread so that needs to threadsafe.  So the coreTask is calling the enrich method for every value in the stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another idea taking advantage of `Task.WhenAny()` to detect when tasks are completing.

For this minimal example, I just assume that the core data and extra data are strings.  But you can adjust for whatever your type is.

Also, I am not actually doing any processing.  You would have to plug in your processing.

Also, an assumption I am making, that is not really clear, is that you are mostly trying to parallelize the gathering of your data because that's the expensive part, but that the enriching part is actually pretty fast.  Based on that assumption, you'll notice that the tasks run in parallel to gather the core data and extra data.  But as the data becomes available, the core data is enriched synchronously to avoid having to complicate the code with locking.

If you copy-paste the code below, you should be able to run it as is to see how it works.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartWork().Wait();
}

private async static Task StartWork()
{
    // start core and extra tasks
    Task<string> coreDataTask = Task.Run(() => "core data" /* do something more complicated here */);
    List<Task<string>> extraDataTaskList = new List<Task<string>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int x = i;
        extraDataTaskList.Add(Task.Run(() => "extra data " + x /* do something more complicated here */));
    }

    // wait for core data to be ready first.
    StringBuilder coreData = new StringBuilder(await coreDataTask);

    // enrich core as the extra data tasks complete.
    while (extraDataTaskList.Count != 0)
    {
        Task<string> completedExtraDataTask = await Task.WhenAny(extraDataTaskList);
        extraDataTaskList.Remove(completedExtraDataTask);
        EnrichCore(coreData, await completedExtraDataTask);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(coreData.ToString());
}

private static void EnrichCore(StringBuilder coreData, string extraData)
{
    coreData.Append(" enriched with ").Append(extraData);
}
```

**EDIT: .NET 4.0 version**

Here is how I would change it for .NET 4.0, while still retaining the same overall design:

- `Task.Run()` becomes `Task.Factory.StartNew()`
- Instead of doing `await` on tasks, I call `Result`, which is a blocking call that waits for the task to complete.
- Use `Task.WaitAny` instead of `Task.WhenAny`, which is also a blocking call.

The design remains very similar.  The one big difference between both versions of the code is that in the `.NET 4.5` version, whenever there is an `await`, the current thread is free to do other work.  In the `.NET 4.0` version, whenever you call `Task.Result` or `Task.WaitAny`, the current thread blocks until the Task completes.  It's possible that this difference is not really important to you.  But if it is, just make sure to wrap and run the whole block of code in a background thread or task to free up your main thread.

The other difference is with the exception handling.  With the `.NET 4.5` version, if any of your tasks fails with an unhandled exception, the exception is automatically unwrapped and propagated in a very transparent manner.  With the `.NET 4.0` version, you'll be getting `AggregateException`s that you will have to unwrap and handle yourself.  If this is a concern, make sure you test this beforehand so you know what to expect.

Personally, I try to avoid `Task.ContinueWith` whenever I can.  It tends to make the code really ugly and hard to read.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // start core and extra tasks
    Task<string> coreDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => "core data" /* do something more complicated here */);
    List<Task<string>> extraDataTaskList = new List<Task<string>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int x = i;
        extraDataTaskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => "extra data " + x /* do something more complicated here */));
    }

    // wait for core data to be ready first.
    StringBuilder coreData = new StringBuilder(coreDataTask.Result);

    // enrich core as the extra data tasks complete.
    while (extraDataTaskList.Count != 0)
    {
        int indexOfCompletedTask = Task.WaitAny(extraDataTaskList.ToArray());
        Task<string> completedExtraDataTask = extraDataTaskList[indexOfCompletedTask];
        extraDataTaskList.Remove(completedExtraDataTask);
        EnrichCore(coreData, completedExtraDataTask.Result);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(coreData.ToString());
}

private static void EnrichCore(StringBuilder coreData, string extraData)
{
    coreData.Append(" enriched with ").Append(extraData);
}
```

Comment: hi. thanks a lot for this, it's exactly what I was looking for! Unfortunatelly I'm on .Net 4.0 :-(
Would you know if something similar could be applied with the .ContinueWith methods?

Comment: @goul: I'm sorry to hear that.  I've edited my post with a .NET 4.0 version that still works very similarly to the .NET 4.5 version. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you probably want is "ContinueWith" (Documentation here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx). That is as long as your enriching doesn't need to be done in a specific order.

The code would look something like the following :

```
var coreTask = new Task<object>(() => { return null; });
var enrichTask1 = new Task<object>(() => { return null; });
var enrichTask2 = new Task<object>(() => { return null; });

coreTask.Start();
coreTask.Wait();

//Create your continue tasks here with the data you want. 
enrichTask1.ContinueWith(task => {/*Do enriching here with task.Result*/});

//Start all enricher tasks here. 
enrichTask1.Start();

//Wait for all the tasks to complete here. 
Task.WaitAll(enrichTask1);
```

You still need to run your CoreTask first as that's required to finish before all enriching tasks. But from there you can start all tasks, and tell them when they are done to "ContinueWith" doing something else.

You should also take a quick look in the "Enricher Pattern" that may be able to help you in general with what you want to achieve (Outside of threading). Examples like here : http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/DataEnricher.html

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I was actually playing at the same time with the ConitnueWith, will try what you recommend. Though, task1 & task2 are not enricher tasks, they are data retreival tasks. Enricher is running after they are done. Also would like coreTask to be started in parallel with the rest as timings are: coreTask=7s, ext1=2s, ext2=4s.